# Transformation from Activity to ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

This code basically fetches data from database and display it in a list along with a searchbox which helps in filtering out specific values from list.

Please  check this snapshot!

[image: http://imgur.com/MpkXe]

But the problem is `DataAttach.java` is extended from `Activity` which doesn't support `onListItemClick()`.

If I want to include `onListItemClick()`, 
I must extend the class from `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Here comes the problem.
If I extend the class from ListActivity, I can't include the searchbox in my view.

I'm stuck into deadlock, any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

**DataAttach.java(snippet)**:

```
                    symbolarr = dbM.getSymbol();

                    if (symbolarr != null) {
                        list1 = new String[symbolarr.length];

                        for (int i = 0; i < symbolarr.length; i++) {
                            list1[i] = symbolarr[i];
                        }
                    }

                    // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, symbolarr);
                    // setListAdapter(adapter);

                    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, symbolarr));
```

**DbManager.java(snippet)**

```
            public String[] getSymbol() {
                Cursor cur;
                try {
                    cur = mDb.rawQuery("select symbol,company_name from scrip", null);
                } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                    throw new Error(" *** ERROR in cursor *** " + e.getMessage());
                }

                String[] b1 = new String[1326];
                int x = 0;
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        b1[x] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("symbol"));
                        x++;
                    } while (cur.moveToNext());
                }
                cur.close();
                return b1;
            }
```

**main.xml**

```
    < LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout">

    < EditText android:id="@+id/txt1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:hint="Search">
    < /EditText>

    < ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    < /ListView>

    < /LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually go either way:

1. Define a ListActivity with custom layout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html Note that you MUST set id like this `@android:id/list`.
2. Without `ListActivity`: use [`setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)`](http://setOnItemClickListener%28AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%20listener%29) on your `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks a ton !!

I used the 2nd method.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            // Do here whatever you want
    }

});
```